# Nested Form Model - Run Condition Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, controller

In my Rails app, I have Steps and Questions.  A user can generate a question for any step.

**Step.rb**

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_one :question, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :question, :allow_destroy => :true
end
```

**Question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :step
end
```

I used a nested form to generate a question:

```
  <%= semantic_form_for [@project,@step] do |f| %>
     <%= f.fields_for :question do |question_f| %>
         <%= question_f.text_area :description %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**First, I only want to create a new question if the user actually enters text into the question text area.  How can I prevent the step form from automatically saving an empty question?**  Here is my current step controller:

```
  class StepsController < ApplicationController
      def new
         @step = @project.steps.build(:parent_id=> params[:parent_id])
         @step.build_question
         ...
      end

      def create
        @step = @project.steps.build(params[:step])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @step.save
          ...
      end
   end
```

**Second, I want to run some ruby code when a new question is created.**  In particular, I want to update the updated_at date for the project that contains the question.  Where would I put this in my controller?  I tried creating a controller for the Question model and creating create and new methods, but they weren't called when the step form was submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue can be solved by modifying the nested attributes line in your `Step` class to reject a submitted question if its attributes are all blank, as follows. See the [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) documentation under **:reject_if**.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :question, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

Your second issue could be solved in a number of ways. If you *always* want to update the `updated_at` for a project (also called "touching" it) whenever a question is added to it, you could add a callback to your `Question` class that touches the project. [See this guide on callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :step
  has_one :project, :through => :step

  after_create :touch_project

  private

  def touch_project
    project.touch
  end
end
```

On the other hand, if you only want to touch a question's project in the context of a specific controller action, you can just check whether a question was created and touch the project if so:

```
def create
  @step = @project.steps.build(params[:step])
  if @step.save
    if @step.question.present?
      @project.touch
    end
    # do other stuff for successful save
  else
    # handle failed save
  end
end
```

Also, for future reference, if you have two largely unrelated questions it's better to ask them separately. Combining questions makes it more difficult for others with the same problem to find an answer.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you!  I never knew about the reject_if and will definitely use that in other areas of my app.